# Given a directed graph with a set of connected vertices, find all reachable nodes from any vertex

Tags: sql, sql-server, graph-theory

Having a sample graph ([yEd live](https://www.yworks.com/yed-live/?file=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nadilas/c8b51fc9198b365d898db45e7b4a03a0/raw/751845d841ac1721382105ed37347843ca95a021/Untitled%20Document)):

[image: graph]

These two basic tables defined on SQL Server 2019:

```sql
create table nodes (id varchar(100), name varchar(15)) as NODE;
create table connections (id varchar(100), from_id varchar(100), to_id varchar(100)) as EDGE;
```

Trying to query all reachable nodes, I created this table value function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION calculateNetworkForNode(
    @DiscoverScenarioFor VARCHAR(15)
)
returns @network TABLE (base varchar(15), pathToNode varchar(max), networkMember varchar(15))
begin

    INSERT @network
    SELECT base, pathToNode, networkMember
    FROM (
        SELECT
            nodes.name as base,
            STRING_AGG(nodes2.name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS pathToNode,
            LAST_VALUE(nodes2.name) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS networkMember
        FROM
            nodes,
            connections FOR PATH,
            nodes FOR PATH AS nodes2
        WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(nodes(-(connections)->nodes2)+))
        AND nodes.name = @DiscoverScenarioFor
    ) AS Q
    WHERE Q.networkMember != @DiscoverScenarioFor

    insert into @network (base, pathToNode, networkMember) values (@DiscoverScenarioFor, null, @DiscoverScenarioFor)

    RETURN
end
```

Running this function with the `A` node, I can get all reachable nodes downstream:

```
+------+------------+---------------+
| base | pathToNode | networkMember |
+------+------------+---------------+
| A    | B          | B             |
| A    | E          | E             |
| A    | E->F       | F             |
| A    | B->C       | C             |
| A    | B->C->D    | D             |
| A    |            | A             |
+------+------------+---------------+
```

(Known issue: if `F` had any other inbound links, this would already not work.)

Running the same function above with node `F` results in a rather boring table of:

```
+------+------------+---------------+
| base | pathToNode | networkMember |
+------+------------+---------------+
| F    |            | F             |
+------+------------+---------------+
```

The goal is to modify this function or create a new one to generate the complete network including all connected nodes. So searching with `A` or `F` or any other member of these connected nodes, should always results in the same set of nodes: A,B,C,D,E,F

---

I had another helper function:

```sql
 SELECT @csv = (SELECT STRING_AGG(n.networkMember, ',') as csv
                   FROM (select top 1000 * from calculateNetworkForNode(@DiscoverScenarioFor) c order by c.networkMember asc) as [n])
```

Which turns the above result to a csv string, but the initial issue is still present: the query only sees the downstream nodes and not all of the connected members.

```
issues

A query results: A, B, C, D, E, F
B query results: B,C,D
C query results: C,D
D query results: D
E query results: E,F
F query results: F
```

Any pointers are welcome, where to look/what to read up on to find a solution how all of these queries with the different members could return the same A,B,C,D,E,F network.

Comment: F is a leaf node.  It has an out degree of zero.  Therefore no node is reachable from F.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to interpret the graph as an *undirected* graph, while your current solution interprets the graph as *directed*.

A pragmatic solution could be to create a view `v_connections` which includes all the connections *and* their reverse.

So something like:

```
create view c_connections as
select id, from_id, to_id
from connections
union
select concat(id, '<'), to_id, from_id
from connections;
```

And then replace `connections` in your current procedure with `v_connections`.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good assessment of the situation. I already attempted that as a nested select union in place of connections, but the results were still not good. I might have overlooked something, I will test it again tomorrow.

Comment: I remember now, I couldn't get the view or a nested select to be used in the match clause. `[S0001][13940] Line 18: Cannot use a derived table 'connections' in a MATCH clause.`

Comment: Then maybe use a *materialized* view?